# Views Galleriffic pagination not show

Tags: php, drupal, module, view, themes

When I updated views module 6.x-3.x-dev not show pagination in views Galleriffic 6.x-1.x-dev. http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/Doctor/fa/galleriffic/95 i set Use pager: Paged, 9 items and Style: Galleriffic Gallery Enable Bottom Pager: yes and I added 17 images. Please guide me I want to show pagination, a like this link http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/fa/galleriffic/95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Turn off the Views pager (ie set it to "All items).

2) In the "Style" set the number of thumbnails you want to display before the pager. If you have 17 images you can set it to "9" there.

3) Make sure you have the top or bottom pager turned to "yes" in "Style".

Any luck? I just tested it with views-6.x-3.x so it should work if you have the right settings.